# linux fetch version of an artifact from build log file

Tags: linux, bash

Can we simplify (omit find or do the same in different way) working snippet of code that fetches a version of an artifact from build log file below?

```
find . -name "*.log" | xargs grep -Poa "(?<=artifact-name).*(?=\.extention)" | head -1
```

Edit:
there is a single log file, let say build.log and I have it in 'current' directory
there are multiply artifacts with same version in build log, so I have non unique search result

Comment: Do you know what the log file name is going to be? Do you know what directory the log file will be in? You can eliminate the `| head -1` by using the `-m 1` argument to `grep` (but only if you aren't worried about `xargs` needing to run `grep` more than once for line length limits).

Comment: Are all `*.log` files in same directory? Can you show a sample data from log?

Comment: You're saying *...from build log file*. Is there just one or many? And as @anubhava asks, if many, are they in the same directory? You only need `find` if you need to traverse directories to look in multiple locations. If they're all in one place, then you only need, `grep -Po "..." *.log | head -1`

Comment: that is what I was asking for, thanks, please put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments I've got

```
grep -Poa -m1 "(?<=artifact-name).*(?=\.extention)" *.log
```